# PhpStorm find all skipping results

Tags: phpstorm

When I do a regular search for a string in a file - I find 4 occurrences.

However when I do a global search (search all: <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F</kbd>), PhpStorm tells me there's only one occurrence.

Why?

[image: PhpStorm global search screenshot]

(Here I know that there are more occurrences. I'm concerned that I'm missing out on results on other searches.)

Comment: *"Here I know that there are more occurrences. I'm concerned that I'm missing out on results on other searches."* Disable grouping by occurrences then... (if that's what you mean by "missing out on results on other searches").

Comment: Not familiar with "grouping by occurrence".
What I meant is that PhpStorm might be hiding search results I'm not aware of.

Comment: Just click on "funnel" icon in Search results toolbar (top right icon there) -- it will disable/enable grouping by occurrence types. Right now you are seeing `Unclassified occurrences` only. But there will be other types: `Usage in comments`, `Usage in string constants` etc

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Wasn't aware of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just click on "funnel" icon in Search Results toolbar (top right icon there) -- it will disable/enable **grouping by Usage Type**.

Right now you are seeing "Unclassified occurrences" only. But there will be other types:

- "Usage in comments"
- "Usage in string constants"
- etc

---

On this screenshot such grouping is enabled and you see the same file listed twice: 4 occurrences in 1 group and 1 in another

[image]

The same results but without grouping by usage type -- all 5 results in one place

[image]